# Building addons for Node.js on Mint17

Tags: node.js, c++11, compiler-errors, linux-mint, node-gyp

I am trying to build some example addons for Node on Linux Mint 17. I keep getting errors. I have tried to change the compiler to clang and also tried using [NAN][1] but I am still getting errors

the clang compiler generates less errors than g++, but I still get

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@1.0.2
gyp info using node@0.10.30 | linux | x64
gyp info spawn python
gyp info spawn args [ '/home/someuser/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args       '/home/someuser/workspace/nonameproject/anothertest/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/someuser/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/someuser/.node-gyp/0.10.30/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/someuser/.node-gyp/0.10.30',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/someuser/workspace/nonameproject/anothertest',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory `/home/someuser/workspace/nonameproject/anothertest/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/addon/addon.o
clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno-tree-vrp'
make: *** [Release/obj.target/addon/addon.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/someuser/workspace/nonameproject/anothertest/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/someuser/local/lib/node_modules/node-    gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/someuser/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/someuser/workspace/nonameproject/anothertest
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.30
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

If I use the G++ compiler with NAN I get:

gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
    make: Entering directory `/home/someuser/workspace/nonameproject/anothertest/build'
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/addon/addon.o
    In file included from ../addon.cc:11:0:
    .././sync.h:2:8: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘-’   token
      * NAN - Native Abstractions for Node.js
        ^
    ../addon.cc: In function ‘void InitAll(v8::Handle<v8::Object>)’:
    ../addon.cc:23:30: error: ‘CalculateSync’ was not declared in this scope
         NanNew<FunctionTemplate>(CalculateSync)->GetFunction());
                              ^
    make: *** [Release/obj.target/addon/addon.o] Error 1
    make: Leaving directory`/home/someuser/workspace/nonameproject/anothertest/build'

If I use G++ without NAN, I get:

```
make: Entering directory `/home/someuser/workspace/nonameproject/mytest/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/binding.o
../binding.cc:6:19: error: ‘FunctionCallbackInfo’ in namespace ‘v8’ does not name a type
 void Method(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
               ^
../binding.cc:6:23: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no type [-    fpermissive]
 void Method(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
                   ^
../binding.cc:6:43: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     void Method(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
                                       ^
../binding.cc: In function ‘void Method(int)’:
../binding.cc:8:28: error: no matching function for call to  ‘v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*&)’
   HandleScope scope(isolate);
```

and so on ....

Can someone please explain what the issue is, and how I might fix my environment to compile a basic Node addon example ? Is it to do with C++11 or something broken in V8 ??

Comment: Do you have a link to the source for your `addon.cc`? It can't find `CalculateSync`. Are you sure you declared it before you try to use it?

Comment: for the top ones I was using the example from here https://github.com/rvagg/nan/tree/master/examples/async_pi_estimate

Answer (score 0):

In the last case it is because you are trying to use code for a newer version of v8 than the one your are linking to (whatever is bundled in Node 0.10.30).